# Selecting based on distance and change in elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, elevation, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to find areas near a series of roads that are withing 500 ft of the road, and have a change in elevation of +50 ft. I have been provided a 2 ft contour of the area, and a centerline layer for the roads in question. My thought process was to intersect the roads and topo, to create points which I could then create the 500 ft buffer from. From there, I am not sure how to proceed and select from this the areas of elevation im looking for

Comment: What is the file type of the contours?

Comment: It is a File Geodatabase Feature Class.

Answer (score 4):

I would:

1. Make a raster dtm from the contours
2. Use the raster to make the road line 3D
3. Buffer the roadline to make a 500ft 3D Buffer in the same resolution as the dtm
4. Subtract the road-buffer raster from the dtm raster
5. Set all values < 50 in the result to NoData.
6. Convert raster to points.

You now have a point dataset with an attribute that shows how much more than 50ft they are above the road  (in a perpendicular distance).  There will be other approaches but this one springs first to mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert contours to DEM ([Topo to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/topo-to-raster.htm))
2. Change DEM to integer type ([Int](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/int.htm))
3. Run [Euclidean Allocation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-allocation.htm), where feature source = roads, input value raster = integer DEM, and set maximum distance to 500'
4. [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm): Con("Integer DEM" - "Euclidean Allocation">50,1,0). Results in binary raster showing pixels where difference is > 50' within 500' of the road. Could also output DEM value.